# rearrange associative array based on unique value php

Tags: php, arrays

Given this:

```
array("Peter"=>"Marketing", "Clark"=>"Accounts", "John"=>"Accounts");
```

I would like to get an array with following result:

```
array(2) { ["Marketing"]=> array(1) { [0]=> "Peter" } ["Accounts"]=> array(2) { [0]=> "Clark" [1]=> "John" } }
```

What i have tried so far ->

```
$rearrange = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
  if(array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
     $rearrange[$value] = $key;
  }
 }
```

Comment: What you tried so far? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the `array_key_exists` but you almost had it:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    $rearrange[$val][] = $key;
}
```

- You `foreach` as `$val` but then use `$value` which doesn't exist
- You need to dynamically append a new element `[]`

Comment: thanks for the answer could you also explain this code

Comment: What's unclear?  The bullets at the bottom explain your issues.